# Convert one dimensional key-value array into two dimensional kay-value array every nth key with new key names

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

[image]

And I need to translate it into this:

[image]

Some things to know about the `$startArray` is that it is dynamic based on the amount of people submitted on a form. Each person always has just those three fields though (`custom_12`, `custom_13`, `custom_14` aka `fName`, `lName`, `email`). So if there were 5 members, the 5th members `fName` would be the key `custom_12-5` in the start array.

I've been looking around on stackoverflow for a question just like this and I was not able to find one. What would be the steps taken and possible array functions or anything else for creating the `$endArray` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually a builtin function for this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

For example, `array_chunk($startArray, 3)` will give you the base for your new array, you'll just need to then iterate through it and rename the keys.

Alternatively, just iterate through the array yourself and add the values to a new array depending on the index of the current iteration.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking for a function like that and could not find it. I used that `array_chunk` to create a middle array and then used `array_map` to convert it. I'll post what I ended up with.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Charlie's advice, I came up with this.

```
$startArray = array(
    'custom_12' => 'john',
    'custom_13' => 'johny',
    'custom_14' => 'john@johny.com',
    'custom_12-2' => 'bob',
    'custom_13-2' => 'bobby',
    'custom_14-2' => 'bob@bobby.com',
    'custom_12-3' => 'don',
    'custom_13-3' => 'donny',
    'custom_14-3' => 'don@donny.com'
);

$middleArray = array_chunk($startArray, 3);

$endArray = array_map(function($val) {
    return array(
        'fName' => $val[0],
        'lName' => $val[1],
        'email' => $val[2]
    ); 
}, $middleArray);

echo "<pre>";
    print_r($endArray);
echo "</pre>";
```

And the output is exactly what I wanted:

[image]